# Find String (Keyword) in title and description using Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**First:** I am opening in a loop some urls and get the title and the description of the html code. **(Works)**

**Second:** I Want to check if there is a given String (Keyword) in the Title or Description. **(not Working)**

---

```
# 2 - Beautifulsoup: Soll Keywords suchen und Schema.org
kw = "optiker"
seite = obj_det.get('result',{}).get('website')
try:
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(seite).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
    desc = soup.findAll(attrs={"name":"description"})
    title = soup.title.string
except:
    title = "Zugriff verweigert"
    desc = "Zugriff verweigert"
kwindesc = kw in desc
kwintitle = kw in title
print(title)
print(desc)
print(kwindesc)
print(kwintitle)
print("-----")
```

---

Always i get **False** on my Screen. But there are definitely titles with the string "optiker" in it.

Comment: What is the type of `desc` and `title`?  Is it some sort of node object?

Comment: i dont know. i am pretty new in learning python. i tried e.g. `kwindesc = kw in str(desc)`. Is also not working.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the page you are trying to scrape?

Comment: You can inspect the type of the object with the `type()` function.  What does `print( type(desc) )` report?

Comment: www[.]optiker-bode[.]de - see the title there is the string "optiker". so i should have a true.

Comment: @dsh: `<class 'str'>` - so i compare a string with a string. should work! or not? **edit:** there is a additional class `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`. even there is no description the class is `<class 'str'>`

Comment: So the reason the `in` operator didn't do what you expected is because `desc` is a `ResultSet`, not a string. The ResultSet in fact does not contain the string you seek.  See dstudeba's answer showing how to extract the text of the description from the set of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `desc` variable is an array of tags, not a string (for findAll).  The information you want is in the `content` attribute of the `meta` tag.  I revised your code a bit and the below is working.  Note the extra steps to pull the `content` out and the use of `find` instead of `findAll`.  Also edited to add case insensitive comparison.

```
url = "http://www.optiker-bode.de/brillenauswahl/marken"
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

kw = "optiker"
#seite = obj_det.get('result',{}).get('website')
try:
    #req = urllib.request.urlopen(seite).read()
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")
    desc = soup.find("meta",attrs={"name":"description"}).get("content")
    title = soup.title.string
except:
    title = "Zugriff verweigert"
    desc = "Zugriff verweigert"
kwindesc = kw in desc.lower()
kwintitle = kw in title.lower()
print(title)
print(desc)
print(kwindesc)
print(kwintitle)
print("-----")
```

The output is

```
Optiker Bode | Marken
Ob Armani, JAGUAR, LIEBESKIND, Michael Kors, Oakley, Porsche, Ray-Ban oder Zeiss: Lassen Sie sich von unserer großen Markenauswahl inspirieren!
False
True
-----
```